# Insert Large html markups inside jquery variable error

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

im builng a web game and im stuck tryning to append the `html-markup` for a `jquery-ui dailog` box.I am currently getting the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number` error in chrome. I have tryed the `appendTo` method for large blocks of data before,but i was wondering is the a limit on the amount of `html-elements` you can place inside a jquery varable? because i find myself having to work around this every day ant tips?
note: please read the question carefully before you answer . Is there a way to store large blocks of (html code/ text) static or dynamic,  inside a `jquery variable`?

jquery code :

```
 <script>
                    var vari = "<?= $UserSpacesAvA ; ?>";
                    var btn = "<button id='d_pis_btn'>Place in shop</button>";
                    $(vari).appendTo(document).dialog({
                        closeOnEscape: false,
                        modal        : true,
                        draggable    : false,
                        height       : 400,
                        width        : 500,
                        resizable    : false,
                        title        : 'Give Your new <?=ucfirst($morph); ?> A Home!',
                        buttons      : [
                            {
                                text: 'Done!',
                                click: function() {
                                    $(this).dialog("destroy").remove();
                                    }
                             },
                        ],
                        open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").remove(); },
                    });
                    $('.popi select').chosen({});
                    $(btn).appendTo('.set').on("click",function(){

                    });
                    </script>
```

Php code :

```
function UserPlaces($userData,$dataExpected,$type){
    $dat = "<div class='popi' id='pop'><fieldset class='set'><legend>Location:</legend>";
    $x = explode(",",$type);
    foreach($x as $s){
        switch($s){
            case 'rooms':
            // bring out rooms
            $dat .= "<label>Room:</label><select id='d_room_select'>";
                if(count($userData["locations"]['r']) < 1){
                    $dat .= "Insufficient Space";
                }else{
                    $int = 1;
                    foreach($userData["locations"]['r'] as $x){
                        $dat .= "<option value=\"$x\">Room Number $int</option>";   
                        $int++;
                    }
                }
            $dat .= "</select><br><br>";
            break;
            case 'shops':
            // bring out shops
            $dat .= "<h4>Is this snake for sale ?</h4><br><label>Shop:</label><select id='d_shop_select'>";
            if(count($userData["locations"]['r']) < 1){
                    $data .= "No Shops";
                }else{
                    $int = 1;
                    foreach($userData["locations"]['s'] as $x){
                        $dat .= "<option value=\"$x\">Shop Number $int</option>";   
                        $int++;
                    }
            }
            $dat .= "</select><br><br><label>Price:</label>
            <input id='d_shop_price_snake' name='d_shop_price_snake'><br><br>
            ";
            break;
            case 'shows':
            // bring out shows
            break;
        }
    }
    $dat .= "</fieldset></div>";    
    return $dat;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide an example of the javascript AFTER it has been output by php.  We don't know what the values of the variables will be...

Comment: it a lot of options eg. <option value="".md5().rand().time()."">$name</option>

Comment: What I mean is, you've got a few php variables and inline code snippets in the javascript, we don't know what they will look like, so could you post the actual script that you would see in the browser?  It's hard to help diagnose the problem without seeing the actual output.

Comment: @appclay i cant render the content because , its depending on what a user select. it was a simple enough question with the code i provided... is there a limit on jquery vatibles?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question on limits, but try using jQuery Templates:
http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/